# Fourier transform symbolic expression from Laplace transform symbolic expression with "$s=j2\pi f$"

Tags: laplace-transform, fourier-transform, symbolic-computation

I just wanted to know under which conditions can we have the Fourier transform symbolic expression from The Laplace transform symbolic expression by replacing "$s$ with "$s=j2\pi f$" ?

I mean from a mathematical point of view.

**EDIT 1:**

Excuse me but anyone could give me examples of transformations when the substitution is possible and when this is not the case ?

Regards

Comment: $F(s)$ should exist at $Re(s)=0$. In other words, the ROC of $F(s)$ should contain the imaginary axis $\sigma = 0$.

Comment: -@Poypoyan . Thanks ! would you have an example where this is the case and another where the correspondance can't be applied ?